# Python: how to put initial centroids on specific data points in k-means?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, k-means, centroid

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9]
df['y'] = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3]
df['val'] = [1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1]

k = 2
centroids = {i + 1: [np.random.randint(0, 10), np.random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(k)}

plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='blue')
for i in centroids.keys():
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color='red', marker='^')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot centroid]

I want to put the initial centroids on data points with the highest value. Then, in this case, the centroids should be located on data points with coordinates (2, 2) and (6, 6).

```
   x  y  val
0  3  3    1
1  2  2   10
2  4  3    1
3  3  4    1
4  4  5    1
5  6  6    8
6  8  5    1
7  7  4    1
8  8  4    1
9  9  3    1
```

Comment: Are you using the `KMeans` estimator from scikit learn? If so, you can pass an array giving the initial centers. See the `init` parameter [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). Or are you asking how to construct that array in the first place?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, I am asking how to write python code to let me place the centroids on the nodes with the highest value because I did not use scikit learn here. I wrote my own codes for kmeans.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the dataframe by `val` column to get the indexes of top `k` values and then slice the dataframe using `df.iloc`.

---

Sorting in the descending order:

```
df = df.sort_values('val', ascending=False)
print(df)

   x  y  val
1  2  2   10
5  6  6    8
0  3  3    1
2  4  3    1
3  3  4    1
4  4  5    1
6  8  5    1
7  7  4    1
8  8  4    1
9  9  3    1
```

Slicing the dataframe:

```
k=2 # Number of centroids
highest_points_as_centroids = df.iloc[0:k,[0,1]]

print(highest_points_as_centroids )

   x  y
1  2  2
5  6  6
```

You can obtain the x,y values as a numpy array by `highest_points_as_centroids.values`

```
array([[2, 2],
       [6, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

---

EDIT1:

Or, more succinctly (as suggested by @sharatpc)

```
df.nlargest(2, 'val')[['x','y']].values
array([[2, 2],
   [6, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

EDIT2:

As OP commented that they want the centroids to be in a dictionary:

```
centroids = highest_points_as_centroids.reset_index(drop=True).T.to_dict('list')
print(centroids)
{0: [2L, 2L], 1: [6L, 6L]}
```

If the dictionary keys are strictly needed to start from 1:

```
highest_points_as_centroids.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
highest_points_as_centroids.index +=1
centroids = highest_points_as_centroids.T.to_dict('list')
print(centroids)
{1: [2L, 2L], 2: [6L, 6L]}
```

Comment: you don't need to slice the dataframe. just use nlargest to get the top 2: `df.nlargest(2, 'val')`; or `df.sort_values('val',ascending=False).head(2)`

Comment: if you want x and y from the outputs then:  `df.nlargest(k, 'val')[['x','y']]` or `df.sort_values('val',ascending=False)[['x','y']].head(k)`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about `nlargest`. I added that to the answer.

Comment: @akilat90 I tried your codes, but when i plot, the two centroids are not located on [2, 2] and [6, 6] like I want. I want it to show like this "{1: [2, 2], 2: [6, 6]}" when we print(highest_points_as_centroids). What should I do?

Comment: @sharatpc When I plot figure with the code you suggested, I could get the right coordinates, but the two centroids were not on nodes with coordinates [2, 2] and [6, 6] in the plot. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: `centroids=df.nlargest(k, 'val')[['x','y']]
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='blue')
plt.scatter(centroids.x, centroids.y, color='red', marker='^')
plt.show()` the red marker will superimpose on the blue

Comment: @sharatpc Thank you so much. That's what I want. Anyway, I have one more question. When I print('centroids =', centroids), I want it to show like this: centroids = {1: [2, 2], 2: [6, 6]}. What should I do?

Comment: @sharatpc I tried this, but it got errors: 
-> c = df.nlargest(k, 'fi')[['x', 'y']]
-> centroids = {i + 1: [c.x.values, c.y.values] for i in range(k)}
-> print(centroids)

Comment: added an answer to address this and previous

Comment: @arizamoona Edited the answer to get the centroids in a dictionary without a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer @arzamoona's further questions, in one place:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9]
df['y'] = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3]
df['val'] = [1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1]

k = 2
centroids=df.nlargest(k, 'val')[['x','y']]

plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='blue')
plt.scatter(centroids.x, centroids.y, color='red', marker='^')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And then to add the centroid values to a dictionary:

```
{i:v for i,v in enumerate(centroids.values.tolist())}
{0: [2, 2], 1: [6, 6]}
```

Comment: You can use `to_dict` to convert the centroids to a dictionary without a for loop.

Comment: but that would give a spread: `{'x': {1: 2, 5: 6}, 'y': {1: 2, 5: 6}}`

Comment: You have to change the `orient` argument. Check the Edit2 of my answer

Comment: nice pandas way. :)

Comment: @sharatpc Sorry, I want to use `for i in centroids.keys():
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color='red', marker='^')` with `{i:v for i,v in enumerate(centroids.values.tolist())}`, but it got error. What should I do?

Comment: save the output of the dictionary into an object, say d. and then in the for loop replace, centroids with d.